# How can I fix my Canon rebel XT?

Tags: canon, troubleshooting, repair, canon-350d

My camera Canon Rebel XT has suddenly gone of order in the sense that:

1. When I turn my camera ON and take a pic, I cannot take a second picture.
2. I have to turn it OFF and back ON again to be able to take another picture. Such continuous ON/OFF toggle is needed.
3. The screen comes up and show the picture I snap but once it goes away, it never come back until I turn the camera back OFF / ON and take a second picture.
4. No button work. Menu button doesn't do any thing. I can delete a picture though but once screen goes dark, I cannot work with any button.

I called Technical Support of Canon but they said that it seems like an internal problem which a user cannot fix. Furthermore, he told me that the bad news is that Canon now does not provide support for Rebel XT.

He offered to go with Canon's royalty / loyalty program to get a refurbished camera body in place of this. Cameras available with them range from $400 to $2000 from T4i to 5D Mark III.

I am struggling to go with either T4i ($400 - $500) and 7D ($780) but just thought to ask you guys if there is still a way I can get my rebel XT fixed?

Other suggestions are very welcome too.

Thanks.

Comment: a newer camera is certainly not a mistake, but if you love your xt, you'll find plenty used ones really cheap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with what Canon Tech Support said; this sounds like an internal problem and it's unlikely you can fix it without sending it into Canon for repair.

The Rebel XT is a ten year old camera body. I recently sold one and all I could get was about $40. Given the probable cost of repair, you're looking at a repair cost at least 2-3X the value of the camera body, and that sounds like a very poor bargain.

My advice is to recognize your XT has had a long and fruitful career and it's time for it to retire. I'd strongly suggest the T4i as a replacement if you want to go the refurbishment option. you'll find it takes significantly better images than your XT did as a bonus, because technology has moved forward massively. I would suggest if you could afford it to go with the 70D, since I think that's a killer camera with the most modern technology inside, but if that's out of the range, any of the T3i-T4i-T5i are all great bodies, each with incremental improvements.

You own't regret upgrading. the improvements in modern bodies are well worth it.

Comment: Every time I pickup my old Rebel XT I'm amazed at how small the LCD screen is. Beyond all of the obvious sensor upgrades and such, modern LCD screens are not something I would ever want to give up!

Answer (score -2):

Canon's office in Chennai and Bangalore (India) does repair XT. Last year March 2014, I got mine done (not same nature of repair)

Comment: But it's now a year later.